# How can I select and delete lines of text in vi?

Tags: unix

If I want to select particular text of line and delete lines, how can I do that in vi (give the simplest means)?

Answer (score 32):

You can also use `V` in view mode to launch "VISUAL LINE" mode. Select your lines and type `d` to delete them.

Comment: That is, `Shift + V`.

Comment: What if V mode is not implemented (as in old Vi implementations?)

Answer (score 16):

Move to the line you want to delete, either using the arrow keys or the <kbd>j</kbd>/<kbd>k</kbd> keys, and type <kbd>`dd`</kbd>. You can then save and exit by typing <kbd>`:x`</kbd> (or <kbd>`ZZ`</kbd>). A number can also be prefixed to <kbd>`dd`</kbd> to delete multiple lines, e.g. <kbd>`3dd`</kbd> deletes 3 lines.

For more Vi commands, take a look at this [handy Vi cheat sheet](http://www.lagmonster.org/docs/vi.html).

Comment: dd is the quickest way to delete a line.

Answer (score 3):

go to the first line you wish to delete, and type (in view mode) `d[x-1]` to delete x lines.

Answer (score 3):

Another tip: if you want to delete a text paragraph, move to beginning of that paragraph with **{** and then type **d}**

Or, in other words, **{d}**

Comment: Or `dap`, delete a paragraph

Comment: @grawity: `dap` doesn't work for me in Vi.

Comment: @Josh: 97% of the time, when someone says "`vi`", he either means "`vim`" or "`vim` running in vi-compatibility mode". So I suggested a `vim`-specific command (see also `:help text-objects`).

Comment: @grawity: Sorry, I *am* running **Vim**, but `dap` still has no effect.

Comment: @Zaz: Perhaps your `.vimrc` file had other settings, or perhaps @user1686's had different settings.